# responsive layout for ul and li - window width CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I'm trying to make a responsive website with li but it is really hard to achieve it. What I want to do is that each of leftContainer and rightContainer has multiple li boxes with maximum 3 boxes in a row. When I reduce the size of the window width, I want them to become 2 boxes in a row each and when I reduce more, for example,

```
if($(window).width() <= 700) {
    // 1 li box each for both leftContainer and rightContainer }
```

Something like this. the below is the code that I've written

http://codepen.io/hk0424/pen/womQxq

Comment: Have you considered using media queries or bootstrap classes for this?

Comment: You should look into using `display: flex;` - it pretty much does what you want to do.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie `display: flex` is not supported in all browser. So if you want to achieve cross border solutions then `display:flex` is not a very good option. See this [link](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) for reference.

Comment: Hi have u got the answer?

Comment: @NishantKumar Meh. It's mostly supported in all new versions of all major browsers, even though IE11 doesn't work 100% without some minor hacks. IE11 is, however, something that shouldn't be used to begin with. Also, the site will still work, it just won't look exactly the same. However, "pixel perfect" is bullshit, and not something that should be a criteria for developing.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Being a developer myself i can agree with you that ie11 should not be used but you will find very few clients who will agree to this. I personally have come across clients who want uniform design even on IE6. Atleast the layout. So in that case you have to find alternate ways to keep the design uniform.

Comment: No. I have to find other clients. Because idiocy will not stand, sorry to say. Working? Yes. Looking the same? Hell no. Unless they pay for it, per hour, full rate. Then sure. But I doubt they wanna pay $200 / hour for something that stupid.

Answer (score 0):

## Avoid fixed width if you want to make elements responsive.

You must avoid giving fixed width for making the elements responsive. For achieving your desired result, you can change the css of the li as follows:

```
html {
    text-align: center;
}

#container {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#leftContainer{
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
    left:0px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#rightContainer {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    right:0px;
}

#leftContainer li, #rightContainer li{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    
}

.leftbox, .rightbox{
    background-color: grey;
    width: 185px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 5px;

}
```

As you can see i have replaced max-width in #container to max-width: 100%.   And for inline element you dont have to write `margin: 0 auto` to align it in center as `text-align: center` on the parent element does the same.

Comment: is there any way i can achieve this by Jquery?